# JQuery Date Plugin

Tags: jquery, date, format

Does anyone know a jquery date plugin, or an alternative jquery/javascript method to transform a default formatted date or a dd/mm/yyyy to a 'human readable' date for example

5/04/2013

5th April 2013

? Iunderstand this could be done manually with making our own array etc...

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: What are you doing with this data?  I typically change my date format in my server-side code.

Answer (score 1):

The most awesome plugin I have used for date parsing which has multiple functionalities is:

http://momentjs.com/

Moment supports multiple date formats, can display time as a factor of duration elapsed, can read multiple formats compared to the native JavaScript library.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use a library...keep it simple and unbloated...

http://jsbin.com/oyekaj/1/edit

```
var date = '5/04/2013';
var months = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','Auguest','September','October','November','December'];

function daySuffix(d) {
    d = String(d);
    return d.substr(-(Math.min(d.length, 2))) > 3 && d.substr(-(Math.min(d.length, 2))) > 21 ? "th" : ["th", "st", "nd", "rd", "th"][Math.min(Number(d)%10, 4)];
}

var dataArray = date.split("/");
var newDate = new Date(dataArray[2], dataArray[1]-1, dataArray[0]);
var dateString = newDate.getDate()  + daySuffix(newDate.getDate()) + " " + months[newDate.getMonth()] + " " + (newDate.getYear()+1900);

console.log(dateString);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty awesome and stable:
http://www.datejs.com/